# Javascript for loop innerhtml doesn't work

Tags: javascript, for-loop, innerhtml, redundancy

```js
    class GenerateArray {

        constructor() {
            this.arrayCode = document.getElementById('code');
            this.BaseCode = document.getElementById('preCode');
            this.startCode = document.getElementById('startC');
            this.endCode = document.getElementById('endC');
            this.question = "";
            this.prefix = "";
            this.description = "";
            this.answer = "";
            this.id = "";
            this.Name = "";
            this.answerDIV = "";
            this.count = 0;

        }

        generateQuestionPart() {

            this.question = document.createElement('input');
            this.question.setAttribute('type', 'text');
            this.question.id = 'question' + this.count;
            this.question.className = 'question';
            this.question.placeholder = 'What is the question?'

            this.prefix = document.createElement('input');
            this.prefix.setAttribute('type', 'text');
            this.prefix.className = 'prefix';
            this.prefix.id = 'prefix' + this.count;
            this.prefix.placeholder = 'The prefix of the question that belongs to the link'

            this.description = document.createElement('input');
            this.description.setAttribute('type', 'text');
            this.description.id = 'description' + this.count;
            this.description.className = 'description';
            this.description.placeholder = 'Add the description that is going to be in the info pop up';

            this.answerDIV = document.createElement('div');
            this.answerDIV.className = 'answerDIV' + this.count;
            this.answerDIV.id = 'AnswerDivId';

            this.answer = document.createElement('button');
            this.answer.setAttribute('type', 'button');
            this.answer.id = 'answer';
            this.answer.className = 'answerN' + this.count;
            this.answer.innerHTML = 'Add Answer';
            this.answer.onclick = function (e) {
                for (let i = 0; i < NewArray.count; i++) {
                    if (e.target.className.endsWith(i)) {
                        NewArray.id = document.createElement('input');
                        NewArray.id.setAttribute('type', 'text');
                        NewArray.id.id = 'id' + i;
                        NewArray.id.classList.add('id');
                        NewArray.id.placeholder = 'Add the ID of the answer';

                        NewArray.Name = document.createElement('input');
                        NewArray.Name.setAttribute('type', 'text');
                        NewArray.Name.id = 'Name' + i;
                        NewArray.Name.className = 'name';
                        NewArray.Name.placeholder = 'Add the text that is on the answer button';
                        // console.log(e.target.className);

                        document.getElementsByClassName('answerDIV' + i)[0].appendChild(NewArray.id);
                        document.getElementsByClassName('answerDIV' + i)[0].appendChild(NewArray.Name);
                    }
                }
            }


            document.getElementsByClassName('create')[0].appendChild(this.question);
            document.getElementsByClassName('create')[0].appendChild(this.prefix);
            document.getElementsByClassName('create')[0].appendChild(this.description);
            document.getElementsByClassName('create')[0].appendChild(this.answerDIV);
            document.getElementsByClassName('create')[0].appendChild(this.answer);
            this.count++;
            // console.log(NewArray.answer.length)
        }

        writeArray() {
            let basis = document.createElement('p');
            basis.innerHTML =
                "    class QuizPart {\n" +
                "        constructor(questionText, chosenAnswer, prefix, questionDescription) {\n" +
                "            this.questionText = questionText;\n" +
                "            this.chosenAnswer = chosenAnswer;\n" +
                "            this.prefix = prefix;\n" +
                "            this.questionDescription = questionDescription;\n" +
                "        }\n" +
                "    }\n" +
                "\n" +
                "    class ChosenAnswer {\n" +
                "        constructor(id, name) {\n" +
                "            this.id = id;\n" +
                "            this.name = name;\n" +
                "        }\n" +
                "    }";

            this.BaseCode.appendChild(basis);

            let startC = document.createElement('p');
            startC.innerHTML = "let Quiz = [";

            for (let i = 0; i < this.count; i++) {
                let code = document.createElement('p');

                let output = "new QuizPart('" + document.getElementById('question' + i).value + "', [";

                let answers = document.querySelectorAll("input#Name" + i)
                console.log(answers.length);

                for (let y = 0; y < answers.length; y++) {
                    output += "new ChosenAnswer('" + document.getElementById('id' + i).value + "', '" + document.getElementById('Name' + i).value + "'),"
                }

                output += "], '" + document.getElementById('prefix' + i).value + "',";
                output += "'" + document.getElementById('description' + i).value + "',";

                code.innerHTML = output;

                this.arrayCode.appendChild(code);
            }
            let endC = document.createElement('p');
            endC.innerHTML = "]"

            this.startCode.appendChild(startC);
            this.endCode.appendChild(endC);
            // console.log(this.count.length);
        }
    }

    NewArray = new GenerateArray();
    NewArray.generateQuestionPart();
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.container{
    height: 1000px;
    width: 800px;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 5px;
    left: 50%;
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, 5%);
    transform: translate(-50%, 5%);
}

.QPB{
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    background-color: orange;
    font-size: 40px;
}

.question{
    width: 100%;
    height: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#answer{
    width: 100px;
    height: 35px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.prefix{
    width: 100%;
    height: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.description{
    width: 100%;
    height: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.id{
    position: relative;
    width: 90%;
    height: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-left: 10%;
}

.name{
    position: relative;
    width: 90%;
    height: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-left: 10%;
}

.CreateArray{
    width: 100px;
    height: 35px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
    <title>Hoi</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="create">
        <button id="QuestionPartBtn" class="QPB" type="button" onclick="NewArray.generateQuestionPart()">+</button>
    </div>
    <div class="result">
        <button id="CreateArray" class="CreateArray" type="button" onclick="NewArray.writeArray()">Create Array</button>
    </div>
    <div class="preCode" id="preCode"></div>
    <div class="startC" id="startC"></div>
    <div class="code" id="code"></div>
    <div class="endC" id="endC"></div>
</div>
```

I created this system that makes an array with information that a user fills in in input fields.
The input fields are dynamically generated, so I use a for loop to show them all in an innerHTML that eventually creates the array.

My code:

```
            this.answerDIV = document.createElement('div');
            this.answerDIV.className = 'answerDIV' + this.count;
            this.answerDIV.id = 'AnswerDivId';

            this.answer = document.createElement('button');
            this.answer.setAttribute('type', 'button');
            this.answer.id = 'answer';
            this.answer.className = 'answerN' + this.count;
            this.answer.innerHTML = 'Add Answer';
            this.answer.onclick = function (e) {
                for (let i = 0; i < NewArray.count; i++) {
                    if (e.target.className.endsWith(i)) {
                        NewArray.id = document.createElement('input');
                        NewArray.id.setAttribute('type', 'text');
                        NewArray.id.id = 'id' + i;
                        NewArray.id.classList.add('id');
                        NewArray.id.placeholder = 'Add the ID of the answer';

                        NewArray.Name = document.createElement('input');
                        NewArray.Name.setAttribute('type', 'text');
                        NewArray.Name.id = 'Name' + i;
                        NewArray.Name.className = 'name';
                        NewArray.Name.placeholder = 'Add the text that is on the answer button';
                        // console.log(e.target.className);

                        document.getElementsByClassName('answerDIV' + i)[0].appendChild(NewArray.id);
                        document.getElementsByClassName('answerDIV' + i)[0].appendChild(NewArray.Name);
                    }
                }
            }
```

For loop:

```
            for (let i = 0; i < this.count; i++) {
                let code = document.createElement('p');

                let output = "new QuizPart('" + document.getElementById('question' + i).value + "', [";

                let answers = document.querySelectorAll("input#Name" + i)
                console.log(answers.length);

                for (let y = 0; y < answers.length; y++) {
                    output += "new ChosenAnswer('" + document.getElementById('id' + i).value + "', '" + document.getElementById('Name' + i).value + "'),"
                }

                output += "], '" + document.getElementById('prefix' + i).value + "',";
                output += "'" + document.getElementById('description' + i).value + "',";

                code.innerHTML = output;

                this.arrayCode.appendChild(code);
            }
```

The problem is with the second loop. Whenever I create 3 input fields for one question and I generate the innerHTML code it does show me all 3, except that they are all the first input field and the second and third aren't used as seen in the following screenshot:[The problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/48vOT.png)
if i change i to y: [Problem 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xyQvD.png)

(My FiddleJS link):https://jsfiddle.net/thijsl0705/1s98gumk/1/

Comment: in the second loop change the i's to y's

Comment: @DCR Yes but if i I do that all the value's are the same so in the first part you get the first values from all the questions and the second one you get all the second values (Added a screenshot)

Comment: @Teemu I didn't re ask my question I fixed that problem a couldn't get the loop right this is a different question

Comment: You will get a faster answer if you provide a working snippet that shows your problem

Comment: @DCR I'll add it

Comment: OK ... Don't create indexed ids, they're error prone and hard to maintain, even when created dynamically. Use classes to group elements, and [a map object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) to bind data to the elements.

Comment: @Teemu but is it possible to add the value of the user input fields to a map object? (I never used it)

Comment: Sure it's possible, maps are working great with dynamically created elements, and also with event.targets. The value of the member can be an object, in which you can include what ever data you need, like related elements, text data, values ... anything. Maybe you could provide the full code of your app ex. at https://jsfiddle.net/ , then we could rebuild the code to utilize a view model instead of endless DOM traversing and complex looping. But please don't forget to update the question here, it really needs a working snippet with which the issue can be reproduced.

Comment: @Teemu Alright thanks! I'll definitely look into that. I will add the code to jsfiddle and I already added a snippet. I think I'll just restart with coding if that's the best way

Comment: @Teemu Just one more question. Do you have something of a preview because I can't seem to figure out how to use maps and use them to create elements like I did in my old code.

Comment: Now when I've seen your code, you might also benefit [cloning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode), but the use of it also provides `id`less code.

Comment: @Teemu Alright i'll look into that too. But I think that i'll first try too fix this and then re write it all.

Answer (score 0):

I entered a,b,c then add answer, d,e then hit the plus sign and add f,g,h,i,j then create array. then hit the plus sign and add 1,2,3,4,5 and create the array and get:

let Quiz = [

let Quiz = [

new QuizPart('a', [new ChosenAnswer('d', 'e'),], 'b','c',

new QuizPart('f', [new ChosenAnswer('i', 'j'),], 'g','h',

new QuizPart('a', [new ChosenAnswer('d', 'e'),], 'b','c',

new QuizPart('f', [new ChosenAnswer('i', 'j'),], 'g','h',

new QuizPart('1', [new ChosenAnswer('4', '5'),], '2','3',

]

]

what exactly is the problem?  what do you want to do?  Looks like you might be missing a closing ) for each new QuizPart

Comment: Well the create array button needs to be pressed whenever you filled in everything. What you did was correct, except the problem is adding multiple answers to one quizpart. When you do that it just adds the first answer to all the answers instead of the second and third ones you added. It just duplicates the first answer when you add multiple answers. Try adding 1 quizpart with multiple answers and you'll see what i mean when you create the array at the end

Comment: ok I added a.b.c and then two answers: d,e and f,g and got this: let Quiz = [

new QuizPart('a', [new ChosenAnswer('d', 'e'),new ChosenAnswer('d', 'e'),], 'b','c',

]   what should I have gotten?

Comment: You should've gotton let Quiz = [ new QuizPart('a', [new ChosenAnswer('d', 'e'),new ChosenAnswer('f', 'g'),], 'b','c',